Увеличила память на малюткe рассбери. Как перенести систему на SSD
Докупила 2тб для своей расбери. В данный момент операционная система стоит на обычной sd карте.
2 Вопроса

Как перенести операционную систему на ssd? Надеюсь будут работать шустрей за счет скорости чтения
Так как изначально было настроено так, что все файлы сохраняются sd карточку с 64гб. Как сделать чтобы основным и по умолчанию был ssd диск?




Сначала CloneZilla livecd + Ventoy, Потом расширяешь разделы через Gparted Live. Можно закинуть на тот же Ventoy.
